# Understanding ItemAdding event

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, document-library, event-receivers

I am trying to understand as to when this `ItemAdding` event fires.

Does it fire when user has clicked **new document** button to upload a document library?

Or

Does it fire when user uploads document library, then a form is shown where he enters Title etc., so before he presses **Save** button, this event is fired?

My aim of asking this question is to do some form validation after user presses **Save** button but before item is added. If there is some error in validation then I want to display error message on screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ItemAdding` event is fired when a file is uploaded to the library. `ItemUpdating` is fired when custom properties in the form are saved.

Answer (score -1):

-ing events e.g Item Adding or Updating are the most suitable events for validation.
In your case Item Adding is the event you are looking for.
In addition have in mind that this event is synchronous.